# How to use JMeter proxy server to record websocket traffic

Tags: proxy, websocket, jmeter

I'm using jmeter 2.9 on a MBP 10.7.5.  I'm also using FF 30 as my browser of choice.

I'm trying to create a load test in jmeter by recording my traffic thru the jmeter proxy server.  I started an HTTP Proxy thru jmeter.  In FF, I told it to use the proxy for all protocols [image]

The jmeter proxy server picks up all traffic (I didn't put any exclusions just to check if I had setup something wrong) on stackoverflow, google, etc. as well as to our website.  For some reason, it doesn't pick up traffic that use websocket to connect to our site but it picks up all other non-web socket traffic to our site.

What am I doing that's making it not pick up this traffic?  What setting on my MBP's System Preferences should I check that might be messing me up?  Could it be some network policy that my company has that's affecting me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMeter Proxy is not able to record websocket traffic.

AFAIK none of the websocket plugins have this ability.

Comment: thanks for looking and answering.  aw, that's not the answer i was looking for =(   do i still have to accept and upvote?  j/k, i'll upvote since u took time to reply  =)